# JSON.parse — "unexpected token" with constructed JSON string

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, syntax, token

This throws: **"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token n(…)"** ...

```
var text = "notation: 'fixed', precision: 2";
JSON.parse("{" + text + "}");
```

No clue as to why or how to safely parse.

Comment: Any reason you can't have parsing JSON in the first place?

Comment: Why not just write `{ notation: 'fixed', precision: 2 }` as a JavaScript object literal?

Comment: The reason why I can't parse a JSON string to begin with is because I can't allow it in the options-string that I wish to parse. Those curly brackets are already parsed as something else, so they're are not available in the string so as to stuff JSON inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have wrong `JSON`, you should wrap keys to double quotes, like this

```js
var text = "notation: 'fixed', precision: 2";
text = text.replace(/\'/g, '"').replace(/(\w+):/g, '"$1":');
console.log( JSON.parse("{" + text + "}") );
```

Comment: Thanks, perfect. I made it even a little more fail-proof using >> text.replace(/[\'\"]/g, '"') << so that it can be both single and double quotes.

Answer (score 3):

You should have tried [a linter](http://jsonlint.com/) first.

The problem is that you are using single quote for key/value in your `text` or not using at all.

Your `text` should be:

```
var text = '"notation": "fixed", "precision": "2"';
```

Comment: `2` doesn't necessarily need to be in quotes.

Comment: @Andy you are right. Boolean and integers don't really need quotes.

Comment: Actually, I never knew or expected that keys in json need quotes. I see how that makes them safter (keywords), but I didn't think it was a requirement.

As for which quotes, this also fails: >> var text = 'notation: "fixed", precision: 2'; JSON.parse("{" + text + "}"); <<